# Proofs Involving Real Numbers

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

We have the following rules that must be used in solving the question

> 1. $a>0$ and $b>c$ $\implies$ $ab>ac$
> 2. $a<0$ and $b>c$ $\implies$ $ab<ac$
> 3. $a>b$ and $b>c$ $\implies$ $a>c$

**Prove that the following is true:** $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ is true that

> $$ x>y \implies x^3>y^3$$

Distinguish the cases according to the signs of $x$ and $y$.

I know that there are 4 such cases.

1. $+x$ and $+y$
2. $+x$ and $-y$
3. $-x$ and $+y$
4. $-x$ and $-y$

I have already ruled out that (3) is not possible as this would contradict the whole proof. But after this, I do not know where to proceed.

Comment: Lets look at the first case.  $x>y>0$.  Then since $\color{blue}{x}>0$ and $x>y$ we have $x\color{blue}{x}>y\color{blue}{x}$.  Furthermore since $x>y$ we have $yx>yy$, combining these together we have $xx>xy>yy$ implying $x^2>y^2$.  Another application of the same process shows $x^3>y^3$.

Comment: @JMoravitz And by implying that $x^2>y^2$ is that a sufficient enough proof to say that then $x^3>y^3$?

Comment: Technically no, implying $x^2>y^2$ is not enough to show that $x^3>y^3$, however $x>y>0$ and $x^2>y^2$, one can do the same thing again exactly like before to show $x^3=x^2x>y^2x>y^2y=y^3$.  I didn't include it in my initial comment because writing it out for the second set of steps is exactly like having written it out for the first set of steps.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah yes, now I see where you are going at. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As $x>y$.

$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy)=(x-y)((x+y/2)^2+3y^2/4)>0$

Answer (score 0):

So, let's use @JMoravitz comment to proceed in the demonstration. We have that

> $a>0 \,\,, b>c \implies ab>ac\tag{1}$
>
> $a<0\,\,,b>c \implies ab < ac\tag{2}$
>
> $a>b\,\,,b>c \implies a>c\tag{3}$
>
> $c< b \,\,, b < a \implies c < a\tag{3}$

The first case is when both are positive ($x> 0$ and $y> 0$) and is exactly as he pointed out. We must have $x > y$ as the hypothesis. So

$$x > y \stackrel{x^2>0 \text{ use }(1)}{\implies} x^2>xy \implies x^3 > x^2y \stackrel{y>0,x> y \text{ use }(1)}{\implies}x^3> xy^2 \implies x^3> y^3$$

Let us see the case when both are negative. Then $x< 0$ and $y< 0$. We get that $xx > 0$ and then we use $(1)$

$$x> y \implies x^3> x^2y$$

But now see that $x > y$ so, because that $x< 0$ we have by $(2)$ that $x^2<xy$. And using $(2)$ with $y< 0$ and $x> y$ we have that $xy < y^2$. Using $(3)$ with these two results

$$x^2< xy\tag{1'}$$

$$xy < y^2\tag{2'}$$

We get then using $(3)$ that $x^2 < y^2$

$$x^2 < xy, xy < y^2 \stackrel{(3)}{\implies}x^2< y^2 \stackrel{y< 0}{\implies} x^2y > y^3$$

But then

$$x^3 > x^2 y\,\, ,\,\,  x^2y > y^3 \implies x^3 > y^3$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

$\begin{array}\\
x^3-y^3
&=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)\\
&=\frac12(x-y)(2x^2+2xy+2y^2)\\
&=\frac12(x-y)(x^2+2xy+y^2+x^2+y^2)\\
&=\frac12(x-y)((x+y)^2+x^2+y^2)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$x^3-y^3$
has the same sign as
$x-y$.

I prefer this
rewriting of
$x^2+xy+y^2$
as
$\frac12((x+y)^2+x^2+y^2)$
(rather than
$(x+y/2)^2+3y^2/4$)
because it is
symmetrical in
$x$ and $y$
like 
$x^2+xy+y^2$.